# How to check container log of tomcat?

Tags: tomcat, catalina, catalina.out

How do I check the container log of tomcat?

I get this error from the catalina.out log:

```
SEVERE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal One or more listeners failed to start. Full details will be found in the appropriate container log file
```

But where can I find the "appropriate container log" that this log is referring to?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You'll find the referenced log file in the same directory containing the log referencing the other log file.  With a default installation of Tomcat, the directory is `$CATALINA_HOME/logs`.  The log file containing the information referenced will usually be the one named with the hostname on which Tomcat is running.  On a simple server (e.g. development environment) this is `localhost.<datestamp>.log`.  The additional error information can be found in this log file at the same timestamp as the noted reference in the referring log file.

Answer (score 28):

I bumped into the same issue while working on a web application.

Tomcat logs did not show full stack trace and application has more than one listeners, it may get challenging to figure out the issue.
After some browsing, below is what helped me find the error.

Create a file **logging.properties** with the following content, place it inside **Apache-tomcat\webapps\MyApp\WEB-INF\classes**  and restart the Apache Tomcat server.

```
org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].level=INFO
org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].handlers=java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler
```

Comment: Hello, Where should I create the file `logging.properties`? Thanks.

Comment: Inside WEB-INF/classes, for example,
**Apache-tomcat\webapps\MyApp\WEB-INF\classes**
Edited answer.