# Tomcat issue: i try to deploy a WAR file but i get this message :The origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource

Tags: tomcat, tomcat7, netweaver

I try to deploy a war file that I put in the tomcat/webapp file and I got this message

> HTTP 404 The origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists.
>
> [image: The error message]

Detailed log:

- Location:

  > [image]
- Content:

  > [image]

Comment: That sounds a bit like file permissions, except you're on Windows. Can you check the various Tomcat logs for any more information?

Comment: The second image you've just posted says "SEVERE: One or more listeners failed to start. Full details will be found in the appropriate container log file". (In general it might be better if you can just paste the relevant lines of text if you can identify them rather than a screenshot.) Can you find the container log file for more information?

Comment: which one? I added a printscreent of the logs file . I could not find container log file.

Comment: [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36617732) says it's the localhost.timestamp one. But it's often worth looking at the stdout and stderr ones too, if not all of them.

Comment: Aug 14, 2018 4:11:08 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class com.datango.pdb.collaborator.CollaboratorServletContextListener

Comment: I don't know Datango PDB Collaborator sorry, but hopefully there's a full stack trace with that exception that you can use to track down and solve the problem?

Comment: INFO: Deploying web application archive C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 7.0\webapps\MyManager1.war
Aug 15, 2018 10:12:36 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.TldConfig execute
INFO: At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
Aug 15, 2018 10:12:36 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: One or more listeners failed to start. Full

Comment: Have you solved it? I have the same problem.